# Computation of $n$-th order difference of falling factorial

Tags: factorial, recurrence-relations, finite-differences

I was reading a difference equation textbook and came across a problem. The question asks to compute ${\Delta}^nt^{\underline3}$ for $n=1,2,3,...$, where $t^{\underline3}$ is the falling factorial "$t$ to the $3$ falling" and ${\Delta}^n$ is the $n$-th order difference operator.

However, there is a theorem that says ${\Delta}^nt^{\underline{r}}=rt^\underline{r-1}$. Therefore If I am right, had if been $n$ is known (say 2), the solution would have been as easy as

${\Delta}^2t^{\underline3}={\Delta}3t^{\underline2}=6t^{\underline1}=6t$

How will the solution be for $n=1,2,3,...$ please?I really wish someone will help.

Comment: I don't mean the theorem must be used, I just want to see how the solution will be. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since $t^{\underline3}=t(t-1)(t-2)$, it's aisy to see that ${\Delta}^nt^{\underline3}=0$  if $n \geq 4$.

for $n=3$, we have: ${\Delta}^3t^{\underline3}=6$

Comment: How will it be $0$ Mohamed? I thought $t^{\underline{r}}=\dfrac{1}{(t+1)(t+2)...(t-r)}$ if $r=-1,-2,-3,...$?

Comment: @YYG: but your question wase about $r=3$

Comment: Yes Mohamed, it is for $r=3$, but when we continue taking the difference, the value of $r$ keep reducing from $3$ to $2,1,0,-1,...$.

Comment: ok i welll try for this

Comment: Okay I will be grateful, am waiting. @Mohamed

Comment: see this: http://www.sjsu.edu/faculty/watkins/antidiff.htm

Comment: In the link you have sent, the $\Delta$ operator is of single power. i.e. $n=1$.